# Loading Scene from ID into ArcGIS JavaScript API 4: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Tags: arcgis-server, 3d, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have created a city engine web scene,and I am trying to display the 3d-visualisation view on sceneview by using the portal Item Id of my webscene. But I am getting

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

How to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <title>Load a basic WebScene - 4.0beta3</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0beta3/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0beta3/"></script>

  <script>
    require([
      "esri/views/SceneView",
      "esri/portal/PortalItem",
      "esri/WebScene",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(SceneView, PortalItem, WebScene) {
       var scene = new WebScene({
        portalItem: new PortalItem({
          id: "022290763bc243bbb5329c879e1dbd3a"
        })
      });
    var view = new SceneView({
        map: scene,
        container:"viewDiv"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is in fact correct. We can see this because changing the portal ID to the one from the [sample code](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/sample-code/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=webscene-slides) like so:

```
var scene = new WebScene({
        portalItem: new PortalItem({
          id: "51c67be4a5ea4da6948a40210ddfab1a"
          // use to be 022290763bc243bbb5329c879e1dbd3a
        })
      });
```

Works as expected. As such it must be something to do your portal item. Due to the fact that the ArcGIS JavaScript API is minified/obsfucated it is quite hard to deduce why this is happening. The common cause of ILLEGAL token is to do with rogue characters in JavaScript/JSON. The full explanation can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal). Some things to check:

1. Is the item shared to publicly on your Portal/ArcGIS Online?
2. What does your scene contain exactly? Is there anything unusual in there that may be causing the error?